Does the common source transimpedance amplifier topology work only for small signals?
I am trying to learn about transimpedance amplifiers and I came across the common source transimpedance amplifier topology as can be seen in the image below.
It is referenced from the following article: A. Atef, M. Atef, E. E. M. Khaled and M. Abbas, "CMOS Transimpedance Amplifiers for Biomedical Applications: A Comparative Study", in IEEE Circuits and Systems Magazine, vol. 20, no. 1, pp. 12-31, Firstquarter 2020. Keywords: {Power demand;Medical devices;Biomedical monitoring;Pulse oximetry;Blood pressure measurement},

In the article it is said that the transimpedance gain at dc=-Rf. My question is, is it only for small IPD changes (small signal) or is the result still valid for the large IPD changes (large signal). I will appreciate any help.

That's a highly unprofessionally drawn circuit considering it's an IEEE publication.

Hi Andy, Its a general topology article and maybe they didn't specify everything. But still, I want to know why do you think it is unprofessional just for the sake of my learning. Thanks.

Ask yourself this: do RF and CPD connect to the gate? Every time I see schematic ambiguities like this I tend to dismiss any article they are in.

Please pardon me if I am wrong. I think the Rf is connected to the gate to provide the gate voltage to the mosfet; otherwise, it will be floating, and the mosfet will be cut off. The CPD is the photodiode capacitance that is coming to the gate because the input signal of the photodiode is to the gate. Please correct me if I am wrong, I just want to learn.

Well, the output can't go outside the range of 0 to Vdd. The linear range will be somewhat less, depending on components and how fussy you are.

Thanks a lot for the reply.  I aim for input currents between 100nA and 10 uA and output voltages between 0 and 4V. I want to work in a low-frequency bandwidth like 100Hz. Will the transimpedance amplifier topology work for what I mentioned, I just need to take care about the output voltage range to be within the vdd?

@VisheshGupta It depends on the transistor. With a transistor model, this is an easy simulation.

Ok thanks, I will try and let you know.

If you pick Rd and the MOSFET such that the output is centred near the Vdd/2 you can get a reasonably large output signal without too much distortion. However, MOSFETs will vary from unit-to-unit. The transimpedance  gain shown is an approximation-  maybe within 10%- and it will vary with the output voltage (which represents distortion).
The limited voltage gain will also limit the bandwidth. Ideally the input voltage of a TIA does not change at all, which mitigates the PD capacitance. Perhaps not an issue in the oximeter application.

Thanks a lot for your reply. I am aiming for input currents between 100nA and 10 uA and output voltages between 0 and 4V. I want to work in a low-frequency bandwidth like 100Hz.

Will the transimpedance amplifier that I mentioned be able to convert these input current ranges. I think a feedback resistor of 500kohm. Is my approach and values of the components suitable?
Can you please suggest any other topology or reference article suitable to my problem?
I really appreciate your help.
Thanks


Why wouldn't you use an op-amp?

Hi, thanks a lot for the reply. I want to do an ASIC design for the TIA on a specific process so that I can integrate the sensor and the TIA on a single chip later.

It seems broadly suitable, maybe with some modifications to guarantee the bias, but I'm not sure if it's the best for an ASIC. An op-amp isn't much area on a modern-ish process such as Sky130.

I am not sure if, with the topology that I am using and the specifications that I just mentioned previously, I will be able to get linear transimpedance gain of Rf. Or the Rf transimpedance gain is only for the small signal input?

Why don't you simulate it with an appropriate transistor model and see how it matches your requirements?
